# Is it possible to automatically create the inverse for a function in iOS?

Tags: ios, function, automation, coordinates

I have a function (this is a simple example, the real function is much more complex):

```
func GPSPointToScreenPoint(OldPoint) -> Point{
    var newPoint:Point
    newPoint.x = OldPoint.x + 10
    newPoint.y = OldPoint.y + 10
    return newPoint
}
```

Is it possible that I can automatically convert the above function, perhaps using built-in methods, to create `ScreenPointToGPSPoint().` from `GPSPointToScreenPoint().` (such that calling `ScreenPointToGPSPoint(GPSPointToScreenPoint(XXXX))` results in `XXXX`)?

Comment: You mean you want to generate ScreenPointToGPSPoint() from GPSPointToScreenPoint() automatically? I am sorry, that's not possible.

Comment: No, It's not possible. Just write it manually.

Comment: why not? The function got a tank of code.

Comment: tank of code? I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: sorry.I mean GPSPointToScreenPoint() with mass code is hard to revert manually.

Comment: No, it's not possible.  Maybe some language somewhere will invert simple functions like that, but not Objective-C, and probably not in Swift.

Comment: "Hard to revert manually" -- you mean it's hard to write `newPoint.x = OldPoint.x - 10; newPoint.y = OldPoint.y - 10`?

Comment: The function above is designed for the question only.

Comment: That means You will have to revert tank of code manually :/

Comment: There are iterative techniques one could employ (esp if you could qualify the domain a bit), but they'll always be less efficient than just writing the inverse function. You generally only contemplate this approach when it's mathematically impossible to write the proper inverse function. You wouldn't do it just because writing the proper inverse function looks a little hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this is not possible. You will have to write it manually.